# Maximum number of square roots of $a \in \mathbb{Z}_n$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

What is the maximum number of square roots an element of $\mathbb{Z}_n$ can have?

Comment: By "maximum" do you mean the maximum number of solutions  $x^2 \equiv a \mod n$ in the integers, for an integer $a$? Your question could mean a lot of things.

Comment: @PatrickDaSilva Yes.

Comment: For odd $n$, it can have as many as $2^r$ where $r$ is the number of distinct prime factors of $n$.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin What about $n=9, 0 \equiv 0^2 \equiv 3^2 \equiv 6^2 \pmod{9}$?

Comment: factor $n$ and use chinese remainder theorem.  for $p$ an odd prime, there are two solutions and these can be lifted to solutions mod $p^r$ by hensel's lemma http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hensel's_lemma.

Comment: @Andrew: $0$ is a special case, because it cannot be reduced to the case of square roots of unity. Note that it also has a *unique* square root in $\mathbb{Z}_p$, rather than $0$ or $2$ as the other elements do.

Answer (score 5):

Let $n$ have prime power factorization 
$$n=\prod_{i=1}^w p_i^{k_i}.$$
By the Chinese Remainder Theorem, the number of solutions of $x^2\equiv a\pmod{n}$ is equal to $s_1s_2\cdots s_w$, where $s_i$ is the number of solutions of the congruence $x^2\equiv a \pmod{p^{k_i}}$.  So all we need to do is to find the number of solutions of 
$$x^2\equiv a \pmod{p^k},$$
for $p$ prime.

A complete answer is complicated. The main difficulty is in determining whether $x^2\equiv a\pmod{p}$ has solutions. For that, a useful tool is the Law of Quadratic Reciprocity.  We concentrate instead on the *number* of solutions of $x^2\equiv a\pmod{p_k}$, when there **is** a solution.

**The case $a$ not divisible by $p$:** If $p$ is an odd prime, and $p$ does not divide $a$, the answer is simple. If the congruence $x^2\equiv a \pmod{p^k}$ has a solution, it has exactly $2$ solutions.

The answer is a bit more complicated if $p=2$.  Suppose that $a$ is *odd*. Then 
$x^2\equiv a \pmod 2$ has exactly $1$ solution. The congruence $x^2\equiv a\pmod{2^2}$ is only solvable when $a\equiv 1\pmod{4}$, and there are then $2$ solutions. Finally, if $k \ge 3$, the congruence $x^2\equiv a\pmod{2^k}$ is solvable only when $a\equiv 1\pmod{8}$, and then there are exactly $4$ solutions.

Now we give a partial examination of the cases that are usually neglected, namely cases where $a$ is divisible by possibly high powers of $p$. The easiest family to deal with is the congruence $x^2\equiv 0 \pmod{p^k}$.

**Case $a=0$:** Let $p$ be prime. Then the congruence $x^2\equiv 0\pmod{p^k}$ has exactly $p^m$ solutions, where $m=\lfloor \frac{k}{2}\rfloor$.  The solutions in the interval $[0,p^k-1]$ are given, respectively, by $p^m t$ and $p^{m+1}t$, where $0 \le t \le p^m-1$.

**General case, $p$ divides $a$:**  Next we look at $x^2\equiv a \pmod{p^k}$, where $p$ is a prime that divides $a$, but such that $a \not\equiv 0\pmod{p^k}$.  We deal only with odd $p$.  (The case $p=2$ would take a few more lines, and we omit it for now.)

Let $a=p^b a'$, where $a'$ is not divisible by $p$, and $1 \le b<k$. If $b$ is odd, the congruence $x^2\equiv a\pmod{p^k}$ has no solution. This is easy to verify, by noting from $x^2\equiv a \pmod{p^k}$, where $p\mid a$ and $k \ge 2$, we get $p^2\mid a$.

So let $b$ be even, say $b=2t$.  If $x^2\equiv p^{2t}a'\pmod{p^k}$, we find that that $x^2\equiv p^{2t-2}a' \pmod{p^{k-2}}$ is solvable. Keep lowering the index of $p$ in this way. We arrive at the congruence $x^2\equiv a'\pmod{p^{k-2t}}$. This will not have a solution unless $a'$ is a quadratic residue of $p$.  If $a'$ is a quadratic residue of $p$, the congruence  $x^2\equiv a'\pmod{p^{k-2t}}$ has $2$ solutions. Each of these solutions yields $p^t$ solutions modulo $p^k$.

The conclusion is that if the congruence $x^2\equiv a\pmod{p^k}$ has a solution, then the congruence has $2p^t$ solutions.

Comment: I'm interested in a tight upper bound.

Comment: For example, say $f(n)$ is the maximum number of square roots of any element in $\mathbb{Z}_n$.  If $f(n)$ is upperbounded by something like $2^{\omega(n)}$, where $\omega$ is [this](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DistinctPrimeFactors.html), like Arturo said above, then, since $\omega(n) \sim \log \log n$, $f(n)$ is bounded by something like $\log n$.

Comment: You also get a lot with $x^2\equiv 3^{2n} \pmod{3^{2n+1}}$.